# adding condition while creating AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I need to create multiple RecordSets for type AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup. But each RecordSets must be created only if it satisfies a condition.
I am aware that we can have a condition before declaring the Properties. but is something possible that we create specific RecordSets depending on conditions.

Something like:

```
LoadBalancerRecordSetGroup:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Condition: HasHostedZoneName
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Ref HostedZoneName
      Comment: 
      RecordSets:
      - Name: !Join [ ".", [!Ref Url, !Ref HostedZoneName ] ]
        Condition: RecordSetCondition1
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: 
          DNSName: 
        Weight: !Ref RoutingWeight
        SetIdentifier: !Ref "AWS::Region"
        

      - Name: !Join [ ".", [ !Ref Url, !Ref HostedZoneName ] ]
        Condition: RecordSetCondition2
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: 
          DNSName: 
        Weight: !Ref RoutingWeight
        SetIdentifier: !Ref "AWS::Region"
        Condition: HostedZoneName
```

If something is not possible then is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

> but is something possible that we create specific RecordSets depending on conditions

Yes, you can do this. Namely, you can use combination of [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) and [AWS::NoValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html#cfn-pseudo-param-novalue).

For example, to conditionally create `RecordSetCondition1` you could do:

```
Conditions:

    ShouldMakeRecordSetCondition1:
        !Equals ["aaa", "bbb"]

Resources:

    LoadBalancerRecordSetGroup:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
        Condition: HasHostedZoneName
        Properties:
          HostedZoneName: !Ref HostedZoneName
          Comment: "a comment"
          RecordSets:
          - !If
            - ShouldMakeRecordSetCondition1
            - Name: !Join [ ".", [!Ref Url, !Ref HostedZoneName ] ]
              Condition: RecordSetCondition1
              Type: A
              AliasTarget:
                HostedZoneId: 
                DNSName: 
              Weight: !Ref RoutingWeight
              SetIdentifier: !Ref "AWS::Region"
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
          - Name: !Join [ ".", [ !Ref Url, !Ref HostedZoneName ] ]
            Condition: RecordSetCondition2
            Type: A
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: 
              DNSName: 
            Weight: !Ref RoutingWeight
            SetIdentifier: !Ref "AWS::Region"
            Condition: HostedZoneName
```